# Norm of sum of positive matrices versus the sum of norms

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, matrix-norms

Suppose that $P_1, \dots, P_k$ are positive $n \times n$ matrices.
Is it true that

$$ \sum_{k} \| { P_k } \| \leq n \left\| {\sum_k P_k} \right\|,$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the operator norm?

---

My effort:

If the $P_j$ are orthogonal projections then the bound is saturated.
I tried to write out the definition $\sum_{k}\langle v,  P_k v \rangle $ and then my intuition is that one could somehow group the $P_k$ according to directions.  I tried to look this up in the book by Bhatia and some googling.

Comment: I think you mistyped your problem, otherwise this is really trivial

Comment: You probably have to use on one side the operator norm and not on the other and may have to commute one sum and one norm

Comment: It most likely is really trivial. What did you find?

Comment: Did you look at it ? This is literally equivalent to $n\geq 1$ I’m quite sure there is a typo

Comment: Sure, thanks! Edited.

Comment: You have the right idea, now you need to show some properties about the operator norm for positive operators :)

Comment: Please define "positive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\|P\|\le\operatorname{tr}(P)\le n\|P\|$ for every $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $P$. Therefore
$$
\sum_i\|P_i\|\le\sum_i\operatorname{tr}(P_i)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum_iP_i\right)\le n\left\|\sum_iP_i\right\|.
$$